# Loading image from server in collection view

Tags: swift

I have tried so many ways to load image from server in collection view, but the lag is still there when scrolling!

this is my `ImageProvider` class:

```
let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()

class ImageProvider: UIImageView {

    var imageUrl: String?

    func loadImage(from urlString: String) {
        self.imageUrl = urlString
        let url = URL(string: urlString)!
        image = nil

        if let imageFromCache = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
            self.image = imageFromCache
            return
        }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, request, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data!)
                if self.imageUrl == urlString {
                    self.image = imageToCache
                }
                imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

setting up data:

```
func setupCVData(cell: TrackCell, item: Audio) {
        cell.title.text = item.name
        cell.url = URL(string: item.url!)!
        if let url = cell.url {
            var imageLink = String()
            (_, _, imageLink) = fetcher.getData(from: url)
            cell.imageUrl = imageLink
            cell.updateImageView()
        }
    }
```

and `updateImageView` function:

```
func updateImageView() {
        self.artwork.loadImage(from: imageUrl)
    }
```

I've tried calling `setupCVData` in `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` and `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

I also used `SDWebImage` with no luck!

So what am I doing wrong here? I can't seem to figure out the problem.

Comment: You wanna do smooth scrolling right? Is there any paging in endpoint that you fetched images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you don't have to create the UIImage object on the main thread. I usually create UIImages in background threads without any problems. UI elements should only be modified on the main thread, however. So when you set the UIImageView's image property, make sure that's done on the main thread.

```
let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data!)
imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if self.imageUrl == urlString {
       self.image = imageToCache
    }            
}
```

Comment: so I should do this part in background?

Comment: yes, make sure that the UIImage is created in a background thread and see if that improves the performance

Comment: If you only experience the lag as new images are downloaded, chances are that this is related to when the actual image is created. This should mean that performance is improved after all images have been downloaded and cached.

Comment: I tried it just now. although the performance improved a little, but it's still the same.

Comment: Are you sure the lag is related to the image? Do you do anything else that might cause lag when each cell is configured and reused?

Comment: What does fetcher.getData(from: url) do?

Comment: I just call `setupCVData` when reusing cells.

Comment: And if you comment out cell.updateImageView() in setupCVData the lag disappears?

Comment: `getData(from: url)` returns names ands links of the files in server and an image url which I use in this code. It's just some html parsing and string functions. I'm sure the lag is related to the images, in early days of this app I just read names and link in `getData`  and there was no lag.

Comment: I'm grasping at straws here... What kind of html parsing are you doing? I have experienced a lot of lag when creating attributed strings from html strings, for example.

Comment: looks like it's because of getData(). I think I should change the topic and question :D but thanks for helping. I really didn't think that would be the problem. I accepted your answer but I can't vote yet.